# b2Body not same size as CCSprite?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have noticed in my game that my b2Bodies are not the same size as my CCSprite's.
This is the code I am using:

```
- (void)addBoxBodyForSprite:(CCSprite *)sprite {
    b2BodyDef spriteBodyDef;
    spriteBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    spriteBodyDef.position.Set(sprite.position.x/CTM_RATIO, sprite.position.y/CTM_RATIO);
    spriteBodyDef.userData = sprite;
    b2Body *spriteBody = world->CreateBody(&spriteBodyDef);
    b2PolygonShape spriteShape;
    spriteShape.SetAsBox(sprite.contentSize.width/CTM_RATIO/2, sprite.contentSize.height/CTM_RATIO/2);
    b2FixtureDef spriteShapeDef;
    spriteShapeDef.shape = &spriteShape;
    spriteBody->CreateFixture(&spriteShapeDef);
}
```

How would I edit that code to just ignore the CTM (PTM) Ratio all together and just be the exact size as the CCSprite? I know I am supposed to use a PTM Ratio but in my case it does not matter.

Thanks!

**Edit1**:

```
- (void)addBoxBodyForSprite:(CCSprite *)sprite {
    b2BodyDef spriteBodyDef;
    spriteBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    spriteBodyDef.position.Set(sprite.position.x/(CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() * CTM_RATIO), sprite.position.y/(CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() * PTM_RATIO));
    spriteBodyDef.userData = sprite;
    b2Body *spriteBody = world->CreateBody(&spriteBodyDef);
    b2PolygonShape spriteShape;
    spriteShape.SetAsBox(sprite.boundingBox.size.width/(CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() * PTM_RATIO)/2, sprite.boundingBox.size.height/(CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() * PTM_RATIO)/2);
    b2FixtureDef spriteShapeDef;
    spriteShapeDef.shape = &spriteShape;
    spriteBody->CreateFixture(&spriteShapeDef);
}
```

**Edit2**:

```
- (void)addBoxBodyForSprite:(CCSprite *)sprite {
    b2BodyDef spriteBodyDef;
    spriteBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    spriteBodyDef.position.Set(sprite.position.x/CTM_RATIO, sprite.position.y/CTM_RATIO);
    spriteBodyDef.userData = sprite;
    b2Body *spriteBody = world->CreateBody(&spriteBodyDef);
    b2PolygonShape spriteShape;
    spriteShape.SetAsBox(sprite.boundingBox.size.width/CTM_RATIO, sprite.boundingBox.size.height/CTM_RATIO);
    b2FixtureDef spriteShapeDef;
    spriteShapeDef.shape = &spriteShape;
    spriteBody->CreateFixture(&spriteShapeDef);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things coming to my mind is :

1. You are testing it on retina screen without setting the scaling factor for your sprite and shape.
2. Try to use boundingBox property instead of contentSize.

in First case :

use - `(CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() * PTM_RATIO);`

Comment: Ok I will try #2 now. But what do you mean by 'first case', can you be more specific?

Comment: sorry for the that i mean that if you are not using the scaling factor and using retina screen for testing.

Comment: when ever you use PTM ratio multiply that with CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() in your case CTM ratio.

Comment: No now it messed up my collision detection. It will not collide with anything now. I have not touched the collision code at all.

Comment: I found out that I do not need to do CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR in this code since cocos2D does it internally. Let me tweak some things around and so how it goes!

Comment: Look at my edit2 code. My b2Body is still like 3x the width of my CCSprite which is messed up. Is there any way to just to ignore the CTM_Ratio and just make it the perfect size since I really do not care about the CTM(PTM)_Ratio in my case?